Convolution between $f$ and $g$, with $g$ being in the Schwartz class. Does it follow that $f \ast g \in C^\infty$?
Usually, the convolution between two functions $f,g$ defined on $\mathbb R^n$ is given by
$$ (f \ast g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y)g(y) \, dy.  $$
Right now I am wondering about a specific property of the convolution between two functions. More precisely, I am wondering about the validity of the following affirmation:

Let $f,g$ be two functions defined on $\mathbb R^n$ such that the convolution $f \ast g$ is well-defined. Moreover, assume that $g \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, where $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ stands for the usual class of infinitely differentiable functions that decrease rapidly at infinity (Schwartz class).  Then, we have that $f \ast g \in C^\infty$.

Context. I am reading an article and trying to understand some of its results. In one of the proofs, the authors seem to use the property that I've highlighted above. The only extra assumption that these authors have is that $f$ is a locally $p-$integrable function on $\mathbb R^n$, that is, $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ (I am not sure if this assumption is relevant to the highlighted property).
I am not very interested in a detailed proof to my question, more like a YES/NO answer so that I can move on in the article. Ideally I am looking for a reference for this kind of results, if someone is aware of one.
Thanks for any help in advance.

If you convolve any two functions you get the smoothness from the smoothest one. So for example, if you convolve an Lp function with a smooth function you will get a smooth function. In this case you are convolving two smooth functions so yes the result will be smooth.

@rubikscube09 Thanks for you comment. In this case I am not putting any assumptions on $f$ (or at most I am assuming that $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$), so that only $g$ is a smooth  function. In this case it is still true that the convolution is also in $C^\infty$ ?

Yes. It is true and a common technique used to construct smooth approximations to non smooth functions (the keyword is usually mollification)

The difficulty seems to be that $f$ can grow at infinity ... if $f$ does not grow faster than all polynomials, then the result is ok (because $\nabla^n(fg) = f\nabla^ng$)

With no further assumptions on $f$, all one can easily deduce is that $f$ defines a distribution $T$ in $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ via
$$
T(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) u(x)\ d^dx
$$
for all $u\in \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathscr{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
The convolution $f\ast g$ is then
$$
(f\ast g)(x)=T(u(x-\cdot))
$$
which normally requires $g$ to be smooth and compactly supported, in order to make sense. If that holds then the convolution $f\ast g\in \mathscr{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathscr{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
In the present situation, an alternative remedy (pointed out in a comment) is to require $f$ to grow at most polynomially at infinity. In that case $T\in\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $T$ is the same as above with the definition ranging over all $u$ in $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ instead of $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The convolution defined using the same formula as before is then in the space $\mathscr{O}_{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of smooth temperate functions. See, e.g.,
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free/351028#351028

Sorry, I think this is a bit overkill to my question. I am not familiar with distributions and so it is quite hard to understand your reasoning. Either way, I would like to ask if you agree with @rubikscube09 comments.
